# Get records with difference on 2 different date ranges in single query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have sales table and have two different date ranges.
i.e, I have total sales between `(2016-12-21 - 2016-12-30) is 100` and for period `(2016-12-11 - 2016-12-20) is 85`. 
Now the result I want is

`100 (sales of 2016-12-21 - 2016-12-30), 85 (sales of 2016-12-11 - 2016-12-20), 15 (difference of both periods)` through single query.

What I am thinking is

```
select *, (a.sales - b.sales) as diff 
from (select id, sum(sales) as sales from salestable where date >= '2016-12-21' and date <= '2016-12-30') a 
join (select id, sum(sales) as sales from salestable where date >= '2016-12-11' and date <= '2016-12-20') b
on a.id = b.id;
```

Is there any other better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when date >= '2016-12-21' and date <= '2016-12-30' then sales else 0
           end) as sales_a,
       sum(case when date >= '2016-12-11' and date <= '2016-12-20' then sales else 0
           end) as sales_b,
       sum(case when date >= '2016-12-21' and date <= '2016-12-30'
                then sales else 0
                when date >= '2016-12-11' and date <= '2016-12-20'
                then -sales
                else 0
           end) as sales_diff
from salestable;
```

If you want the overall sum by `id` (as suggested by your inclusion of `id`), then add `id` to the `select` and add `group by id`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case` to do a conditional sum like this:

```
select id,
    sum_21_to_30, 
    sum_11_to_20, 
    sum_21_to_30 - sum_11_to_20 diff
from (select id,
    sum(case when date >= '2016-12-21' and date <= '2016-12-30' then sales else 0 end) sum_21_to_30,
    sum(case when date >= '2016-12-11' and date <= '2016-12-20' then sales else 0 end) sum_11_to_20
from table group by id) t;
```